# GWT Main.gwt.xml file

Tags: gwt

I have a gwt project with the following directories:

-com.project

-com.project.client

-com.project.shared

-com.project.server

The gwt.xml config file is located in the com.project directory. What value should be in the
`<source>` tag for path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the tag for source with attribute path in the gwt.xml file?  If that's the case, you use those paths for the translatable code (i.e., the code you want compiled from Java to JavaScript).  Typically it's just the client and shared code that you want the GWT compiler to handle so you would set the following:

```
<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />
```

If you were referring to another tag, please forgive me.  :)